# Using delimiters in split

Tags: java, tokenize, delimiter

I'm trying to make a program that tokenizes a source code. How should I tokenize this using split:

```
if a == b
 b = c
```

This is my code:

```
String WITH_DELIMITER = "((?<=%1$s)|(?=%1$s))";
```

^credits to someone from stackoverflow who provided this^

```
String[] tokens = newfile1.split(String.format(WITH_DELIMITER, "(==)|(\\=)"));
```

This code generates:

```
if
a
=
=
b
b
=
c
```

But I want it to be

```
if
a
==
b
b
=
c
```

Comment: Why not split on one or more whitespaces `split("\\s+")`? Anyway for more complex texts regex doesn't seem to be proper tool. You should probably create your own parser.

Comment: It is parsed so that because `==` are 2 tokens. One solution might be to parse on each whitespace. But then you must consider the use of proper intput or checks.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting on whitespace as suggested in comments is one possibility. A slightly better approach is using word boundaries, so that it works on inputs without whitespace (like `if a==b then b=c`):

```
pattern = "\\s*\\b\\s*"
```

This will generate some empty tokens where there are several matches at once (i.e, a whitespace followed by a word boundary or vise versa), like this: `if, "", a, ==, "", b, "", b, =, "", c`, so you'd have to filter them out afterwards.

Comment: when I tried it, there was an error "Pattern.group() line: not available"?